# Global symbol "$line" and "$addr" requires explicit package name

Tags: perl, ip-address

I'm trying to get the output to show a list of ip addresses and login with the corresponding country but I keep getting these errors: Global symbol $line and $addr requires explicit package name. It works fine in Perl but I'm running this script from the server. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $psql = "/usr/local/pgsql/current/bin/psql";
my $db = 'cpi';
my $args = "-U postgres -qc";

my $date = `/bin/date +\%y\%m\%d%H`;
my $reportfile = "/tmp/multiiplogins-$date";

my $sendmail = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -fcpi\@cpi-syndication.com";
my $mailsubject = "Login Report";
my $mailto = 'user@yahoo.com';

my $query = "SELECT userid, login, email, logins, ips FROM (SELECT userid,login,email,       count(userid) AS logins, count(ipaddr) AS ips FROM (SELECT l.userid, u.login, u.email$

my $query2 = "SELECT l.userid, login, email, ipaddr FROM synloginaccess l, synusers u where l.accesstime > (now() - interval '24 hours') and l.type=2 and l.userid=u.userid $

open (REPORT, ">$reportfile");

my $command = qq/$psql $db $args "$query"/;
my $command2 = qq/$psql $db $args "$query2"/;

my $result = `$command`;
my $result2 = `$command2`;

#update IP addresses with country
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::IPInfoDB;

my $g = Net::IPInfoDB->new;
$g->key("api_key");

#we split $login into an array, line-by-line
my @lines = split("\n",$result2);
for my $line (@lines) {
   #now we iterate through every line one-by-one
   $line =~ /(?<ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/;
   my $addr = $g->get_country("$1");
   print "$line " . "| ". "$addr->country_name" ."\n";

 }


    #print REPORT "$result2\n";
    #print REPORT "\n";
    print REPORT "$line " . "| ". "$addr->country_name" ."\n";

  close REPORT;
  mailReport();

 sub mailReport{
     #mail it
     open(MAIL, "|$sendmail");
     print MAIL "To: $mailto\n";
     print MAIL "Subject: $mailsubject\n";
     print MAIL "\n";
     open (INFILE, "$reportfile");
     my @contents = <INFILE>;
```

Comment: Ia this your complete program? Put in `use strict;`, `use warnings;`, and `use autodie;` at the top of your program. These will catch many of your errors, and will probably clean up a lot of your questions. Try that, and then see if you can clean things up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$line` and `$addr` variables are no longer in scope when you try to print them after your for loop:

```
#print REPORT "$result2\n";
#print REPORT "\n";
print REPORT "$line " . "| ". "$addr->country_name" ."\n";
```

I imagine this line is supposed to be commented out.

Comment: I get this as a result though:
160.79.208.82 | Net::IPInfoDB::Result=ARRAY(0x2c88ae8)->country_name

Comment: When you are trying to print the dereferenced value of something in Perl, you can't wrap it in quotes. So `"addr->country_name"` needs to just be `$addr->country_name`. You could also optionally wrap it in the string like this: "${ \$addr->country_name }", but I think the other way is more readable.

Comment: Yeah I tried that but I still got the errors:
Use of uninitialized value $1 in string at synlogin.pl line 39.
Can't call method "country_name" on an undefined value at synlogin.pl line 40.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: What errors, I can't help you diagnose the problem without more information.

Comment: Sorry. I pressed enter and sent the comment before showing the errors:

Use of uninitialized value $1 in string at synlogin.pl line 39. 
Can't call method "country_name" on an undefined value at synlogin.pl line 40.

Comment: Does the code above have your full regular expression? Usually if you want to capture a value there is not a `?` at the front, and non-capturing groups begin with `?:` so I am not sure it is complete.